# Looping through list of values and inserting

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a select that returns employee IDs of type int.  I'd like to use these empId values as part of an insert.  Basically, I need to loop through all IDs, inserting them.  But how is that does done?

I know a cursor can be used for this scenario but isn't there a way to do it without the cursor?

Comment: Never loop through records, get that whole idea out of your head. Looping through records is almost 100% avoidable in SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO 
  table2 
( 
 employeeID 
)
SELECT
  employeeID
FROM
  table1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
INSERT INTO SomeTable
(Column1, Column2, Column3)
SELECT ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC
FROM OtherTable
WHERE ...
```